# Apache Ignite 2.0 Java and .NET: BasicBinaryIdMapper no longer works?

Tags: java, c#, caching, ignite

My goal is to run a Java Ignite node with a .NET client connecting to it. As I've been having some issues I've gone to an even simpler example of not a server/client model but a server/server model. Prior to Ignite 2.0 you could set up a BinaryConfiguration on the Java side like so:

```
// Configure Ignite to connect with .NET nodes
BinaryConfiguration binCfg = new BinaryConfiguration();

binCfg.setIdMapper(new BinaryBasicIdMapper());
binCfg.setNameMapper(new BinaryBasicNameMapper());
```

This works in the sample projects shown here: https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Ignite-Multi-Platform-Cluster/

However, if you take these two working projects and upgrade them from Ignite 1.7.0 to Ignite 2.0.0, you'll now get the following exception (this is from the Java side):

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node's binary configuration is not equal to remote node's binary configuration [locNodeId=2d98d083-859f-4bae-bb9a-16fe00f9f39a, rmtNodeId=d9f68030-79b1-4e41-bd00-1bec44dca9e3, locBinaryCfg={**globIdMapper=org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryBasicIdMapper**, compactFooter=true, globSerializer=null}, rmtBinaryCfg={globIdMapper=**null**, compactFooter=true, globSerializer=null}]

You'll notice that in the above exception that the Java node has the BinaryBasicIdMapper setup, however the remote .NET node does not have this mapper anymore, which is causing this exception.

I've tried the following to no avail:

- Removing the BinaryBasicIdMapper (can connect to the cluster, but can't deserialize objects, get's an "Unknown Pair" exception).
- Creating the BinaryBasicNameMapper with a **true** parameter (to enable simple names). Same "Unknown Pair" exception as above.

I've been scouring the Ignite docs trying to figure out what to do in Ignite 2.0, but I can't find any examples of what to do. Has anyone else faced this issue? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join Java and .NET nodes in Ignite 2.0+ and map types to each other:

- Use `BinaryBasicNameMapper` with `SimpleName` on both sides
- Do not set `IdMapper`
- Register types on both sides with `ignite.binary().type(Foo.class)` (Java) and `ignite.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(Foo))` (.NET)

---

Details:

Ignite.NET 2.0+ employs the same dynamic type registration as Java had before. No need to register types in BinaryConfiguration before starting the node. Normally, you would not need to bother about registering the types at all (like we did with GetBinaryType call) - type is registered automatically on first usage. However,  when more than one platform is involved, you can get this "unknown pair" exception, because each platform registers the type in a separate data structure. Why? Because on deserialization Ignite needs to instantiate an actual class. In .NET this class may be `Foo.Bar.Message`, in Java `org.foo.bar.Message`. So even though both these classes map to the same Ignite binary type (simple name mapper throws away namespace/package), on deserialization we need to know fully-qualified name.

I've updated the [blog post](https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Ignite-Multi-Platform-Cluster/) in question and added working example to [ignite-2.0 branch](https://github.com/ptupitsyn/ignite-multi-platform-demo/tree/ignite-2.0)

Comment: Thanks Pavel, this works! Now I just need to experiment on finding ways to do this in a configuration-type style to make it easy to update. Our application has a lot of types :). Accepting this answer.

Comment: @Eluamous You can also register all types via `IgniteConfiguartion.BinaryConfiguration`, which can be done in XML. However, you would have to provide identical Java `BinaryConfiguration` on all nodes, including .NET, where this is done via `IgniteConfiguration.SpringConfigUrl`. Let me know if you need help with this.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the pointer! I was able to separate out the two configurations (one for Java and other for .NET) and was able define the types in their binary configurations there. I think this will work well!

Comment: Note that even if you already have BinaryBasicNameMapper with SimpleName in ignite.xml, you will STILL need to specify it in C#.